# Are we able to obtain several variables from a single request.security call?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Are we able to obtain serveral variables from a single `request.security` call or only one ? For example in the code below , only `bar_index` will be returned.
I tried to store "`high`" into a root scope alert, but not sure this works reliably, I seem to be getting "`high`" from the current scope, not from the 5 min call.
So what is the right way, only to return single value with request.security ?

Code in picture below:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNsPk.png)

Comment: What is your question? Do you want several variables from request.security or do you want a single value with request.security? Make your request clearer, please. And provide code in your question, do not link out to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can retrieve several variables. `security()` does support tuples.

You can either pass your function and get the return value as a tuple, or pass directly a tuple to `security()`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

f_get_ohlc() =>
    [open, high, low, close]

[o1, h1, l1, c1] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", f_get_ohlc())
[o2, h2, l2, c2] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [open, high, low, close])

plot(o1, "o1", color.white)
plot(o2, "o2", color.gray)

plot(h1, "h1", color.green)
plot(h2, "h2", color.lime)

plot(l1, "l1", color.red)
plot(l2, "l2", color.orange)

plot(c1, "c1", color.purple)
plot(c2, "c2", color.blue)
```

[image]